# How to push a git submodule to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a repo named **ld** with a submodule named **ldapp**, which is a Django project. I want to push the Django project **ldapp** to elastic beanstalk, but I get the warning following warning when running `eb init`:

> Warning: Your directory has not been initialized as a Git repository.
>   To create a local Git repository, run "git init" and then re-run the
>   "eb init" command.

If I continue on and run `eb push` I get:

> git: 'aws.push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. Cannot run
>   aws.push for local repository HEAD:

The way git structures submodules is it actually has the *.git* of the submodule be a **file**, not a **directory**. The following is the contents of the **file** ldapp/.git:

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/ldapp
```

This file tells git to retrieve ldapp's versions from ld's *.git* **directory**. Since the *.git* versioning of ldapp is not present within ldapp itself (but rather within ld's *.git*), running `eb init` and `eb push` fail. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. I had to `git clone` the submodule to get back a standalone Git repository.